# How do I avoid excessive Network File I/O when appending to a large file with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, networking

I have a program that opens a large binary file, appends a small amount of data to it, and closes the file.

```
FileStream fs = File.Open( "\\\\s1\\temp\\test.tmp", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None );
fs.Write( data, 0, data.Length );
fs.Close();
```

If test.tmp is 5MB before this program is run and the data array is 100 bytes, this program will cause over 5MB of data to be transmitted across the network.  I would have expected that the data already in the file would not be transmitted across the network since I'm not reading it or writing it.  Is there any way to avoid this behavior?  This makes it agonizingly slow to append to very large files.

Comment: Have you tried the FileStream.Seek method instead?

Comment: Is there an anti virus scanner active which does an on-access check?

Comment: You might add some information about your end goal (ie. a logging system, or data reporting tool) as the users here might have some suggestions you might not have considered.

Comment: @ChrisW: `FileMode.Append` calls Seek internally.

Comment: From my tests using a 598MB file, I believe you have some other problem. The problem is not the code you posted. On first run, with all system caches cleared, it can take up to seven seconds to write the first 100 bytes with no more that 256KB being read (which is probably buffer-filling for the stream). Subsequent writes taking 80ms, 24ms, and finally 3ms for writes after that. Regardless of the FileMode and FileAccess options I specify.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but I'd suggest using a verbatim string when dealing with file paths, especially UNC, so you don't have a ridiculous number of backslashes in your code.  So instead of
"\\\\s1\\temp\\test.tmp"
You end up with 
@"\\s1\temp\test.tmp"

Comment: AMissico is right; there is more to it than the information I posted above.  I've done more investigation and found that the behavior I reported happens with some files and not with others.  I need to try to determine what is the difference between the 2 cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0xA3 provided the answer in a commment above.  The poor performance was due to an on-access virus scan.  Each time my program opened the file, the virus scanner read the entire contents of the file to check for viruses even though my program didn't read any of the existing content.  Disabling the on-access virus scan eliminated the excessive network I/O and the poor performance.

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx#files) (`CreateFile` is called internally):

> When an application creates a file across a network, it is better to use GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE for dwDesiredAccess than to use GENERIC_WRITE alone. The resulting code is faster, because the redirector can use the cache manager and send fewer SMBs with more data. This combination also avoids an issue where writing to a file across a network can occasionally return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Using Reflector, `FileAccess` maps to `dwDesiredAccess`, so it would seem to suggest using `FileAccess.ReadWrite` instead of just `FileAccess.Write`.

I have no idea if this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could cache your data into a local buffer and periodically (much less often than now) append to the large file. This would save on a bunch of network transfers but... This would also increase the risk of losing that cache (and your data) in case your app crashes.

Logging (if that's what it is) of this type is often stored in a db. Using a decent RDBMS would allow you to post that 100 bytes of data very frequently with minimal overhead. The caveat there is the maintenance of an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have system access or perhaps a friendly admin for the machine actually hosting the file you could make a small listener program that sits on the other end.

You make a call to it passing just the data to be written and it does the write locally, avoiding the extra network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The File object in .NET has quite a few static methods to handle this type of thing. I would suggest trying:

```
File file = File.AppendAllText("FilePath", "What to append", Encoding.UTF8);
```

When you reflect this method it turns out that it's using:

```
  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true, encoding))
{
    writer.Write(contents);
}
```

This StreamWriter method should allow you to simply append something to the end (at least this is the method I've seen used in every instance of logging that I've encountered so far).

Comment: AppendAllText returns void, not File :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Write the data to separate files, then join them (do it on the hosting machine if possible) only when necessary.

Comment: I say this, because the "long answer" is really long, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block and there is no way around it. It's a limitation of Windows file share system.

Answer (score -3):

I did some googling and was looking more at how to read excessively large files quickly and found this link https://web.archive.org/web/20190906152821/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/010401-1.shtml

The most interesting part there would be the part about byte reading:
Besides the more commonly used ReadAll and ReadLine methods, the TextStream object also supports a Read(n) method, where n is the number of bytes in the file/textstream in question. By instantiating an additional object (a file object), we can obtain the size of the file to be read, and then use the Read(n) method to race through our file. As it turns out, the "read bytes" method is extremely fast by comparison:

```
const ForReading = 1
const TristateFalse = 0
dim strSearchThis
dim objFS
dim objFile
dim objTS
set objFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objFile = objFS.GetFile(Server.MapPath("myfile.txt"))
set objTS = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateFalse)

strSearchThis = objTS.Read(objFile.Size)

if instr(strSearchThis, "keyword") > 0 then
Response.Write "Found it!"
end if
```

This method could then be used by you to go to the end of the file and manually appending it instead of loading the entire file in append mode with a filestream.

Comment: -1: Did you notice this was an article from 2001, for VBScript, not for .NET?